# Error while importing pandas. ImportError: cannot import name 'Timestamp' .

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

This is the following error I am getting when I am trying to import pandas in Jupyter Notebook or in Pycharm or in the Python Terminal of Anaconda3.

> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas__init__.py in ()
>
> 25 try:
>
> ---> 26     from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,
>
> 27                              lib as _lib,
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas_libs__init__.py in ()
>
> 3
>
> ----> 4 from .tslib import iNaT, NaT, Timestamp, Timedelta, OutOfBoundsDatetime
>
> 5
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas_libs\tslib.py in ()
>
> 5    "removed in a future version.", FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)
>
> ----> 6 from pandas._libs.tslib import Timestamp, Timedelta, OutOfBoundsDatetime
>
> 7 from pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype import NaT, NaTType
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Timestamp'

and

> C extension: 'Timestamp' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.

I am using Python 3 in Windows 10. How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions on :-

[Contributing to Pandas  -- pandas 0.23.4 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/contributing.html#creating-a-development-environment)

Extra components that might be required are :-
1) Cython OR a release package of pandas